# Getting the entire div sections using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver, nokogiri

I am trying to learn Nokogiri with some scenarios and am parsing the html code right now using it.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML($driver.page_source)
```

In my code I have muliple div sections which has some nested span and div tags as per below:

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3 class4" style="padding: 4px;" id="_28f331c5-3e42-4944-aa3f-15b68f453a2b"> 
  <span class="class5" style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">This is a String Text</span> 
  <div class="class6" dd:contenttype="content_type1" dd:concept="concept1" id="_8c83d6b3-55a1-4e88-b8af-9578bbfdef83">
    <div class="class7"> 
      <div class="class8" dd:contenttype="content_type2" dd:entityid="0" dd:entityversion="0" id="_cb48e502-9d87-451c-a7cf-4df104f21e51"> 
        <div class="class9 class10" dd:btnfloatingstyle="top-right" dd:entitytexttype="resultval" id="_9e48a58b-3f06-4ce1-8a1e-fb7f4c5d1fc0" contenteditable="true"></div> 
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<div class="class1 class2 class3 class4" style="padding: 4px;" id="_28f331c5-3e42-4944-aa3f-15b68f453a2b"> 
  <span class="class5" style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">New String Text</span> 
  <div class="class6" dd:contenttype="content_type1" dd:concept="concept1" id="_8c83d6b3-55a1-4e88-b8af-9578bbfdef83">
    <div class="class7"> 
      <div class="class8" dd:contenttype="content_type2" dd:entityid="0" dd:entityversion="0" id="_cb48e502-9d87-451c-a7cf-4df104f21e51"> 
        <div class="class9 class10" dd:btnfloatingstyle="top-right" dd:entitytexttype="resultval" id="_9e48a58b-3f06-4ce1-8a1e-fb7f4c5d1fc0" contenteditable="true"></div> 
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

What I am looking for is when I pass a string "This is a String Text" as an input to a method, it should look into multiple div sections and return me the appropriate entire div section along with its nested span and div's.

Is there a direct way to achieve what I want using Nokogiri or any other API or will I need to  write a method to traverse through the element, its parent and then the child??

Please suggest the direct way if there is any else I will write my own code to traverse.

Comment: Are you trying to find the innermost div containing your search string?

Comment: No I am trying to get the entire div block. If I pass the argument as 'New String Text' I should get 2nd div block in the above question back which starts with "<div class="class1 class2 class3 class4" style="padding: 4px;" id="_28f331c5-3e42-4944-aa3f-15b68f453a2b"> 
      <span class="class5" style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">New String Text</span>...... </div></div>

Comment: "Please suggest the direct way if there is any else I will write my own code to traverse"? Huh? You're supposed to WRITE THE CODE FIRST, then show it to us, explain why it doesn't work and what it should do. Instead, you're asking someone to write code for you, so you can present it as your own. Read http://sscce.org/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist and http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: I am nowhere asking for the code. I was asking for suggestions if there are any direct methods/functionality for my requirement which I might be unaware of. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get a node based on its child nodes, you will have to use an xpath-selector instead of a css-selector.

To get the div containing the span, do:

```
node = doc.at_xpath('//div[./span[text()="New String Text"]]')
```

Runnable example:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = %q[
<body>
<div class="class1 class2 class3 class4" style="padding: 4px;" id="_28f331c5-3e42-4944-aa3f-15b68f453a2b"> 
  <span class="class5" style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">This is a String Text</span> 
  <div class="class6" dd:contenttype="content_type1" dd:concept="concept1" id="_8c83d6b3-55a1-4e88-b8af-9578bbfdef83">
    <div class="class7"> 
      <div class="class8" dd:contenttype="content_type2" dd:entityid="0" dd:entityversion="0" id="_cb48e502-9d87-451c-a7cf-4df104f21e51"> 
        <div class="class9 class10" dd:btnfloatingstyle="top-right" dd:entitytexttype="resultval" id="_9e48a58b-3f06-4ce1-8a1e-fb7f4c5d1fc0" contenteditable="true"></div> 
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<div class="class1 class2 class3 class4" style="padding: 4px;" id="_28f331c5-3e42-4944-aa3f-15b68f453a2b"> 
  <span class="class5" style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">New String Text</span> 
  <div class="class6" dd:contenttype="content_type1" dd:concept="concept1" id="_8c83d6b3-55a1-4e88-b8af-9578bbfdef83">
    <div class="class7"> 
      <div class="class8" dd:contenttype="content_type2" dd:entityid="0" dd:entityversion="0" id="_cb48e502-9d87-451c-a7cf-4df104f21e51"> 
        <div class="class9 class10" dd:btnfloatingstyle="top-right" dd:entitytexttype="resultval" id="_9e48a58b-3f06-4ce1-8a1e-fb7f4c5d1fc0" contenteditable="true">asdf</div> 
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
</body>
]

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)
puts doc.at_xpath('//div[./span[text()="New String Text"]]').to_html
#=> <div class="class1 class2 class3 class4" style="padding: 4px;" id="_28f331c5-3e42-4944-aa3f-15b68f453a2b"> 
#=>   <span class="class5" style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">New String Text</span> 
#=>   <div class="class6" dd:contenttype="content_type1" dd:concept="concept1" id="_8c83d6b3-55a1-4e88-b8af-9578bbfdef83">
#=>     <div class="class7"> 
#=>       <div class="class8" dd:contenttype="content_type2" dd:entityid="0" dd:entityversion="0" id="_cb48e502-9d87-451c-a7cf-4df104f21e51"> 
#=>         <div class="class9 class10" dd:btnfloatingstyle="top-right" dd:entitytexttype="resultval" id="_9e48a58b-3f06-4ce1-8a1e-fb7f4c5d1fc0" contenteditable="true">asdf</div> 
#=>       </div> 
#=>     </div>
#=>   </div> 
#=> </div>
```

Comment: Aahhaaaaaa Awesome!! Thats what I am looking for. Thanks Justin!! :)